# How does the virial expansion converging, mean that there is no phase transition?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, entropy, phase-transition, virial-theorem

I have a question regarding how the virial expansion relates to phase transition.  I watch the lecture  https://www.coursera.org/learn/statistical-mechanics/lecture/1a5Di/tutorial-3-algorithms-exact-solutions-thermodynamic-limit on coursera at about 15 minutes into the lecture.  It says about 15 minutes into the lecture that the fact that the following series converges for all densities smaller than 1 means that there is no phase transition.  How does it mean there is no phase transition?

The series he is referring to comes from virial expansion:

$$ \frac{V}{N} \frac{\partial log (Z(\eta))}{\partial V} = 1+2(N-1)\pi \sigma^2 \frac{1}{V}+...\frac{1}{V^2}+...\frac{1}{V^3}$$

How does the virial expansion converging, mean that there is no phase transition?

Comment: Isn't your title wrong (i.e., the *not* should be removed)? In any case, even though I haven't time to check what  the precise setting of the lectures you mention is, let me point out that convergence of the expansion of the pressure as a function of the density implies that the pressure is an analytic function of the density, which is clearly incompatible with a usual liquid/vapor phase transition.

Comment: Yes!  Thanks for correcting me, I started to write the inverse contrapositive.  So, the virial expansion that I have written above is used to determine whether or not a phase transition will take place?  part of my confusion is the usage of such an expression.

Comment: The virial expansion provides the equation of state for general gases (including corrections to the perfect gas law). In general, it fails to converge at large densities. This will always be the case if there is a gas/liquid phase transition. Note, however, that failure of convergence does not necessarily imply the presence of such a phase transition.

Comment: okay, so convergence is sufficient but not necessary condition for no phase transition.  and lack of convergence is necessary but not sufficient for phase transition.

Comment: Yes, this is correct.